# Phabricator Is there a way to change default "Accept" policy in "Differential" to require "all" reviews to accept, rather than "some"?

Tags: phabricator

As per 'Differential' documentation:
https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/differential/

> Once everything is satisfied, some reviewer accepts the change and the author pushes it to the upstream.

This means any reviewer can mark the overall review state as 'Accepted', even though some reviewers may have open questions.

Is there a way to change it so review is marked "Accept"ed when *all* reviewers have accepted it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> even though some reviewers may have open questions

This is a bit problematic. Fundamentally if you have an engineer *ignoring* code feedback on a review and pushing the code anyways, that engineer should be talked to separately. The point of flexible code reviews in Phabricator is most people can be trusted the majority of time, and through that the product enables greater workflow speed and keeps things unblocked (and engineers working).

If you don't trust your engineers, tools like Herald (to add blocking reviewers) and Owners (code ownership packages) still achieve most of what you'd likely want.

https://secure.phabricator.com/T731 is the task tracking "all must accept" type rules in the upstream.

Comment: Understood. Ignoring `open questions` is not the most critical factor. What I meant to emphasize is that the author has no way of knowing when everyone is done reviewing. The `all must accept` type of thing in your upstream will take care of this. Thanks.