# How to allow acceptance of own revisions in Differential for specific projects in Phabricator?

Tags: phabricator

In our organisation we have couple of projects shared with third party developers and couple of completely internal projects as well.

Previously there were two of us who were allowed to work on internal projects, but right now I'm the only person left who is allowed to work on them. We have a pretty nice workflow and CI setup around phabricator, so I want to continue to using it and push my changes through [Differential](https://www.phacility.com/phabricator/differential/).

It is not possible because Differential requires a revision to be accepted by someone but author and I don't have any other person who can accept it.

I want to achieve some kind of "single-user" flow where I will be able to accept my own Diffs. Then when we get more employees I can switch back to reviews.

Possible solutions to this problem are:

- Set `differential.allow-self-accept` configuration flag to `true`. But this flag is global and It will allow third-party developers to ignore reviews.
- Write some kind of **auto-accept-bot** and notify it using [Herald](https://www.phacility.com/phabricator/herald/). Then bot will automatically accept Revisions from me using [Conduit](https://secure.phabricator.com/conduit/method/differential.revision.edit/). Drawback is that it looks like the ugliest workaround ever.

---

So the question is, like it was stated in title:

**How to allow acceptance of own revisions in Differential for just a specific set of projects?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the answer to be more philosophical.

So the solution is to **add blocking reviewers for projects with "untrusted" developers using Herald and allow-self-accept option in Differential for now**.

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33622830 for some more info.